# JavaFx: about nodes and scenes

Tags: javafx

I have a problem with my project I have a stackpane that calls an fxml but my fxml gets bugged:
[image]

my fxml main:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ControllerHome">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-background-color: #150;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0fbcf9;">
               <children>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="HOME" size="30" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-family: Quicksand; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: white;" text="Application">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="40.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <children>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="iconUser" glyphName="USERS" onMouseClicked="#xx" size="25" />
                  <Text fx:id="textUser" onMouseClicked="#xx" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-family: Quicksan; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: #485460;" text="Usuarios">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
               <children>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="LIST" size="25" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-family: Quicksan; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: #485460;" text="Requisições">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
            <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <children>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="COG" size="25" />
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-family: Quicksan; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: #485460;" text="Settings">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Text>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <children>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="SIGN_OUT" size="25" />
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-family: Quicksan; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-fill: #485460;" text="Logout">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Text>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <HBox fx:id="subRoot" maxHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="80.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="150.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <StackPane fx:id="mainRoot" layoutX="265.0" layoutY="256.0" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="150.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="80.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

my controller:

```
public class ControllerHome implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private HBox subRoot;
    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView iconUser;
    @FXML
    private Text textUser;
    @FXML
    private StackPane mainRoot;

    @FXML
    void xx(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("xd");
        Pane content = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainContentUser.fxml"));
        mainRoot.getChildren().addAll(content);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        /*
        iconUser.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
            System.out.println("xd");
        });
        textUser.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
            System.out.println("xd");
        });*/
        try {
            HBox menu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("menuUser.fxml"));
            subRoot.getChildren().addAll(menu);

            System.out.println("xdxx");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ControllerHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

my fxml with anchor Pane:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="559.0" prefWidth="811.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f547;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="388.0" layoutY="199.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I don't know what is going on it is not full size and is covering other parts of my screen
I don't know if it's because of the stackpane or some configuration I made.
If anyone can help me on how I can solve this

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX) helps.

Comment: Could you supply imports for the first fxml?

Comment: You do not allow the `AnchorPane` in the included fxml to be resized: You use `USE_PREF_SIZE` for both the min and max constraints restricting the `AnchorPane` to it's preferred size...

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is misusing different Pane types to achive your goal. It would be very hard to point out all the problems this layout has. That is why I publish fxml which provides expected layout. Load it in SceneBuilder and try to manipulate it for better understanding. Remember that order of addition to GridPane (same for every Pane) affects z-order of children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <VBox style="-fx-background-color: green;" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <VBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: pink;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="16.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="16.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
      <StackPane style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```